# Script to disable/enable monitor settings in windows 7

Tags: display, script

Would it be possible to create scripts to disable or enable a monitor in a triple monitor setup?

A work station is being shared with few different users, and each one of them have different requirement. Some of the users require 2 monitor, and some users require 3 monitors. So each time a user logs on he will have to change the display property to meet his requirement.

Is it possible to create scripts to disable or enable the 3rd monitor when user logs on to the workstation?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can do this, at least properly, natively in Windows. But you should be able to accomplish it nicely with MultiMonitorTool from Nir Sofer.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html

> MultiMonitorTool is a small tool that allows you to do some actions
>   related to working with multiple monitors. With MultiMonitorTool, you
>   can disable/enable monitors, set the primary monitor, save and load
>   the configuration of all monitors, and move windows from one monitor
>   to another. **You can do these actions from the** user interface or from
>   **command-line, without displaying user interface.**

You'd download the tool and run (or run at sign in for specific user) a script (you can do a batch file or so) something like:

```
MultiMonitorTool.exe /disable 2 3
```

And:

```
MultiMonitorTool.exe /enable 2
```